# How to  deploy my web app to router 

Tags: router, wireless-networking

When ever I connect my router in a mall or hotel service then I get a login page after connecting to the access point.

I am using DiLnk router. Is this possible to deploy my web  app there?

Comment: I need to know how to deploy an webapp to a router, Does this really an off-topic question? Why does this need to be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something that allows for a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). In general most consumer grade routers are unlikely to support this without alternative firmware like openwrt.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is usually done by intercepting the HTTP requests sent to the access point and redirecting them to the authentication page. Not all access points support that, only the advanced ones do.

Comment: Could you elaborate perhaps on which access points do this, and how to do it?